# Symfony2 Ajax trying to access unrelevant attributes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I am trying to make an Ajax call, to add/remove product from favorites. I think I did everything correctly, however I am getting an 500 Error response with the message: `Impossible to access an attribute ("gallery") on a null variable in MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_details.html.twig at line 37`

Now problem here is that the attribute `gallery` should not even be used and is not specified anywhere in the Ajax, however I get this error.

So this is the Ajax Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.favorite', function (e) {
        $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'favorite',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {id: $this.id},  // this is the products id I imagine?
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.success == false){
                    alert('error')
                }else{
                    $('.btn-toolbar').load(" .btn-toolbar");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The twig:

```
         <div class="btn-toolbar">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <span class="btn" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:ail@gmail.com;'"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
              <span class="btn" onclick="printPage()" ><i class="icon-print"></i></span>
            {% if favorite is defined %}
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="favorite btn"><i class="icon-star-white"></i></a>
              {% else %}
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="favorite btn"><i class="icon-star"></i></a>
              {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
```

And the controller:

```
public function addFavorites(Request $request) {

        $response = new JsonResponse();

        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
        if (!$securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {

            $response->setData(array('success'=>false, 'message'=>'Need to be logged in'));

        } else {

            $requestData = $request->request->all();
            $productid     = $requestData['id'];
            $userId = $this->getUser()->getId();
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->find($productid);
            $favorite = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Favorite')->findOneBy(array(
                'userId'=> $userId,
                'productId' => $productid));

            if($favorite) {
                $em->remove($favorite);
                $em->flush();
            } else {
                $favorite = New Favorite();
                $favorite->setUserId($userId);
                $favorite->setProductId($productid);
                $em->persist($favorite);
                $em->flush();

                $response->setData(array('success'=>true,'message'=>'Added to favorites', 'product' => $product));

            }

        }
        return $response;
    }
```

So this is how things should work in my idea: A user clicks on the star, the response sends products id to the controller. The controller checks if the user is loggd in, if he is it then checks if the user has already favorited this product if yes, remove favorite, if not create a new favorite. If everything was successful refresh the buttons only.

Now the attribute gallery in my twig is the first loop that I iterate in my template and it is before the buttons. Since I am only trying to refresh the buttons why does he need the gallery attribute?:

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
              {% for img in product.gallery.galleryHasMedias|slice(0,3) %}
               <a href="{% path img.media, 'reference'%}" data-lightbox="carousel-images"data-lightbox="carousel-images"> <img width="29%" src="{% path img.media, 'reference'%}" alt=""/></a>
              {% endfor %}
              </div>
              <div class="item">
               {% for img in product.gallery.galleryHasMedias|slice(3,6) %}
               <a href="{% path img.media, 'reference'%}" data-lightbox="carousel-images"> <img width="29%" src="{% path img.media, 'reference'%}" alt=""/></a>
               {% endfor %}
              </div>
            </div>

         <div class="btn-toolbar">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <span class="btn" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:katauskasdomas@gmail.com;'"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
              <span class="btn" onclick="printPage()" ><i class="icon-print"></i></span>
            {% if favorite is defined %}
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="favorite btn"><i class="icon-star-white"></i></a>
              {% else %}
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="favorite btn"><i class="icon-star"></i></a>
              {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Routing:

```
add_favorites:
    pattern:  /favorite
    defaults: { _controller: MpShopBundle:Homepage:addFavorites }
```

Comment: Could you show product_details.html.twig line 37? `MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_details.html.twig at line 37`

Comment: @Ricardo I did show it. Its the last table of code. The line : {% for img in product.gallery.galleryHasMedias|slice(0,3) %} is the 37 line

Comment: product.gallery apparently equals null, you can either check for that before starting the for loop. Or you can check why the product.gallery != null

Comment: No, the product gallery is not null, The images and everything in the template is showing correctly.  Only when I start the ajax call I get this error

Comment: You state this url: 'favorite', In your ajax, it looks like a route_name to me, is it really an url?

Comment: Yes I added my routing in the POST.

Comment: My guess is that because you don't have the / in front of favorite, it's not going to the right URL, (you could check in for example chrome inspector) but changing the URL to `url: '/favorite'` might already do the trick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85418/discussion-between-dominykas55-and-ricardo).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line:

`{% for img in product.gallery.galleryHasMedias|slice(0,3) %}`

Twig says: `Impossible to access an attribute ("gallery") on a null variable in`

So  `product` variable is `null` (error when trying to do `product.gallery`).

From your controller code, it seems that your product is not found by ID provided. So it might be several cases

1. ID is not passed
2. invalid ID is passed
3. there is no product with such ID.